# BizTalk SFTP receive port not picking files larger than 1GB

Tags: sftp, biztalk, biztalk-2013

BizTalk SFTP receive port not picking files larger than 1GB(in my csae i can receive upto 5GB files). Even though it picks the file its very slow and before the whole file is dropped into the file folder the orchestration starts unzipping the zip file and throws error : cannot unzip as the file is being used by another process.Any help?

Answer (score 1):

**What you are seeing is not a problem with BizTalk Server or the SFTP Adapter.**

This is happening because the SFTP Server is allowing the download to start before the file is completely written.  This can be because the SFTP Server is not honoring a write lock or the actual source app is doing multiple open-write-close cycles while emitting the data.

So, this is actually not your problem and not a problem you can solve as the client.

The SFTP Server either needs to block the download or a temporary location/filename must be used until the file is complete.

This is not an uncommon problem, but must be fixed on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue is with SFTP adapter as it doesn't put a lock on the file when doing transfer that is why orchestration tries to unzip that file.I hope this helps you

Comment: @JayMishra To be clear, that's not how it works.  The Orchestration would not do anything until the entire original message is received, regardless of the Receive Adapter/Protocol.  The issues is entirely with the SFTP *server*, not the Adapter or BizTalk.  The SFTP Server is not properly handling an open file.  This is a not uncommon problem.